# How to modify a tpl file using custom module

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a PRESTASHOP module. Is there a way to modify a tpl file using a custom module?

I've just read on PRESTASHOP that it is not recommended to override the tpl file, is there any other solution?

Comment: There are multiple solutions. Which tpl file do you want to modify?

Comment: its the order-carrier.tpl file

Comment: What do you want to modify there? It is a theme file. You can create a copy of your current theme and modify it there. If you want to add custom code or variables, only in this case a custom module is needed (then you can add code with hooks, template modification is not needed).

Comment: i need to retrive a list of shipping from an external api and display it in the list (without saving it in the db), i'm looking a solution to do that, any idea ?

Comment: So it is not about template modifications. Yes, you need a custom module and can use hookDisplayBeforeCarrier() or hookDisplayCarrierList() in it. Or other hooks, it depends on your needs.

Comment: is there any hook to add a shipping price to the total product ?

Comment: For this is hookDisplayCarrierList(). Or you can create a custom carrier module http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+carrier+module.